# How to source environment variable in command line with && combiner?

Tags: shell, scripting, environment-variables

For a NodeJs app, I wrote the following script to deploy the app:

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "source private/create_env.sh && ./deploy.sh",
}
```

`private/create_env.sh` creates environment variables that are used in the `deploy.sh` script.

```
export USERNAME=alphonsio
export SERVER=ftp.example.com
export ...
```

The `&&` combiner prevent the environment variable from being available in the deploy.sh script.

How to make them available in the deploy script?

Comment: @ChrisDavies to be honest, not running a script called `deploy.sh` when sourcing `create_env` failed sounds like a good idea!

Comment: @ChrisDavies:  Ditto: Why do you say that the OP “should” use `;` (rather than `&&`) between two commands where the second depends on the first?

Comment: @MarcusMüller fair point. G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' mainly because I didn't think about the semantic dependency; I was more concerned about the logical requirement. However, having now tried it I can't make it fail in the way that's described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem has nothing to do with `&&`:

`/bin/sh` is usually some other shell trying to mimic The Shell. Many distributions use `/bin/bash` for `sh`, it supports `source`.

On Ubuntu, though, `/bin/dash` is used which does not support `source`. Most shells use `.` instead of `source`. If you are on one of these systems, replace `source` by  `.` in your `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy": ". private/create_env.sh && ./deploy.sh",
}
```

Comment: It works! I wonder how anyone could have guessed that answer. You are awesome! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The && combiner prevent the environment variable from being available in the deploy.sh script.

No it doesn't.

If I have `create_env.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export SOME_CUSTOM_VAR=foo
```

And `deploy.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Value is: $SOME_CUSTOM_VAR"
```

Then running:

```
source create_env.sh && ./deploy.sh
```

Produces:

```
Value is: foo
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `&&` the problem comes from `.`, see my answer.

Comment: I agree that it has nothing to do with the use of `&&`; that’s exactly what this answer says.